# group by a pair of a column sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table in SQL name: pgcPhieuThu

[image]

I want to creat a stored procedure for SoPhieu with:
+ if parameter = 0 then SoPhieu= 'PT-1->n'
else parameter = 1 then SoPhieu= 'BC-1->n'

```
ALTER proc pgcPhieuThu_TaoSoPhieu3 
 @HinhThuc int,@SoPhieu NVARCHAR(50) OUTPUT
as
declare @MaPT INT
SELECT  @MaPT= ISNULL(SUBSTRING(MAX(pgcPhieuThu.SoPhieu),4, LEN(pgcPhieuThu.SoPhieu)),0) + 1
FROM pgcphieuthu
    GROUP BY SUBSTRING(pgcPhieuThu.SoPhieu,1,3)
SET @SoPhieu = CASE WHEN @HinhThuc = 0 then 'PT-'+ CAST(@MaPT AS NVARCHAR(50))
                    ELSE 'BC-'+ CAST(@MaPT AS NVARCHAR(50))
```

but Column 'pgcphieuthu.SoPhieu' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: `group by` only usually makes sense when you're going to get multiple groups in the results; but your `SELECT  @MaPT=` usage means that only a single arbitrary group is going to be selected... can you clarify what you're trying to do here, and what should happen with the other groups that are being ignored? I wonder if what you should *actually* be doing here is a sub-query

Comment: Can you provide an example of the exact output you want, vs the output you're getting.  Also this isn't a c# question as you've written it (is there a reason you're using a Stored procedure vs LINQ->SQL code?)

Answer (score 0):

SoPhieu is not an column in the table. Its an parameter to the stored procedure.
so replace the 'SoPhieu' to 'SoPhieu'with in the stored procedure. It should work then on.